# How to set vertical on image

Tags: html, css

I have some problem setting the image on vertical align. But i try everything to set the image on vertical align but it does not work for me :(

Here's my coding:

```
#skill{
   position: relative;
   transform: translateY(-50%); <---Error for css

}

<div id="skill">
            <img src="image/Adobe_Photoshop_CS4_icon_(2).png" width="50px" height="50px">
            <img src="image/Adobe_Photoshop_CS4_icon_(2).png" width="50px" height="50px">
            <img src="image/Adobe_Photoshop_CS4_icon_(2).png" width="50px" height="50px">
            <img src="image/Adobe_Photoshop_CS4_icon_(2).png" width="50px" height="50px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#skill{      
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your code provides a solution to the question. This will help the OP understand and apply your code as well a future searchers.

Comment: It was my mistake that i misunderstood the question. I apologize

Comment: It's not that you may or may have not understood the question, it's that your answer is "Try this: [code block]". A **good** answer will explain how the code answers the question. An example would be "By setting the <some setting> to <some value> the element will <some desired behavior>..." etc. Answers that have a detailed explanation *along with* a code example are high quality answers and help teach the OP as well as future visitors of this question the missing knowledge that led to this question. It's about teaching. Sorry for not making the previous comment as clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
#skill
{
    position:relative;
}
#skill img 
{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
}
```